# Can't submit after preventDefault

Tags: jquery, validation, submit, uploadify, preventdefault

I use a script for form validation (validationEngine) and a script for file upload (uploadify).

To best manage my form submission:

- validationEngine detects if my form can be sent.
- If I can submit, I upload my files
- Once all my uploaded files (`onQueueComplete` uploadify), I submit my form.

If I make an `alert('foo');` in my onQueueComplete, it works. But if I submit my `selector.submit()` ... nothing happens.

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'fileSizeLimit' : '2048KB',
        'auto': false,
        'swf'      : '<?php echo site_url('public/modules/uploadify/uploadify.swf')?>',
        'uploader' : '<?php echo site_url('public/modules/uploadify/uploadify.php')?>',
        'buttonText' : 'Ajouter...',
        'method' : 'post',
        'formData' : {'userMail' : '<?php echo $userMail ?>'},
        'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
            $('#validator').submit();
        } 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#validator").validationEngine();
    $('#validator').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var canSubmit = $("#validator").validationEngine('validate');
        if(canSubmit)
        {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload','*');
        }
    });
});
```

With this code, all works but submit doesn't work. It's like the event doesn't exist.

Comment: Or the selector is wrong and the element does'nt exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method complicates the task myself. I decided to do a new routine easier.

I let the file load automatically. And I just created elements that I delete.

Anyway, to send my mail, file attachments will be destroyed.

here is my new code and it works.

```
/**
 * uploadify
 * 
 * we add a onUploadStart event to manage the file. uploadify uploads directly our files, but maybe the user missclick
 * and wants to remove some file.
 * 
 * The send action (controller webmail) doesn't upload files, uploadify do that for us.
 * We just need in the post for the name of the file registered in a hidden input.
 */
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'fileSizeLimit' : '2048KB',
        'swf'      : '<?php echo site_url('public/modules/uploadify/uploadify.swf')?>',
        'uploader' : '<?php echo site_url('public/modules/uploadify/uploadify.php')?>',
        'buttonText' : 'Ajouter...',
        'method' : 'post',
        'formData' : {'userMail' : '<?php echo $userMail ?>'},
        'onUploadStart' : function(file){
            $('#uploadList').append('<div class="file"><a href="#" class="deleteFile" rel="'+file.name+'">'+file.name+' - [x]</a><input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="'+file.name+'" /></div>');
        }

    });

    /**
     * the .deleteFile elements are added after domready. We have to attach event click.
     * We remove the parent block to remove a file of mail attachment
     */
    $('#uploadList').on('click','.deleteFile',function(){
        var rel = $(this).prop('rel');
        /*$('input[value="'+rel+'"]').remove();*/
        $(this).parents('div:first').remove();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").cleditor()[0].focus();

    $("#validator").validationEngine();     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

(1) Your selector elsewhere is `#validator`, whereas you are using `validator` in the non-functional call.

(2) You are `preventDefault`ing every `submit` event that originates on `#validator`, so even if the event was correctly triggered it would not execute a submit action. You need to call the native DOM element's `submit` action instead:

```
$('#validator')[0].submit();
```

`[0]` gets the native DOM element from the selection, and you then call the native `submit` function. This means no jQuery handlers are run, so the `event.preventDefault` call you make is also not run, so the event will function.

Comment: it's just a bad bad copy/past for the (1). Sorry ^^. I test your (2) and the event isn't launch. I do a new routine

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be:

```
$('#validator').submit();
```